# document.createElement("tr") not showing up in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml

I have a really annoying problem. I got this bunch of code which runs and should put some information from XML into several table slots.

```
var xmlDoc;
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Load XML
    importXML();
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
});

function importXML() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "adList.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: assignXML
    });
}

function assignXML(myXML) {
    xmlDoc = myXML;
    pushContent();
}

function pushContent() {
    var len = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('advertisement').length;
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        var trElement = document.createElement('tr');
        console.log($(xmlDoc).find('advertisement').eq(i).find('image').text());
        var image = $(xmlDoc).find('advertisement').eq(i).find('image').text();
        var imageTD = document.createElement('td');
        var imageIn = document.createElement('input');
        imageIn.setAttribute('type', 'text');
        imageIn.setAttribute('name', 'imageArr[]');
        imageIn.setAttribute('size', '15');
        imageIn.setAttribute('value', image);
        imageTD.appendChild(imageIn);
        trElement.appendChild(imageTD);
        console.log(trElement);
    }
```

All of the information is there. I can look up the tr in the javascript code with firebug and it works correctly. It isn't throwing any errors. It just doesn't show up on the page or in the html. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're not appending your tr anywhere.....

Comment: Where do you append `trElement` to some table element?

Comment: You need to create table element and add child tr to that and make table element visible. try this - tableElement.style.display = "block";

Comment: I have a table. in the HTML that is blank. How would I append my tr element to the table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this...

```
var trElement = document.createElement('tr');
```

to this...

```
var table = document.getElementById('my_table'),
    trElement = table.insertRow(table.rows.length);
```

***DEMO:*** http://jsfiddle.net/7gDhq/1/